# Bounds checking of std::vector (and other containers) in clang?

Tags: clang, stdvector

In clang, is there a way to enable bounds checking for [] access to std::vectors and other STL containers, preferably when building in debug mode only?

I just spent hours hunting down a subtle bug that turned out to be caused by us accessing past the end of a std::vector. It doesn't need to do anything clever when it detects the error, just trap in the debugger so that I can find out where it happened and fix it in the code.

Is there a way to do this other than "create your own type that inherits from std::vector", which I'd like to avoid?

(I'm using clang version 3.1 if that makes a difference.)

Comment: Yeah, use `at()` instead of `operator[]`. That is defined to give you run time bounds checking

Comment: I would advise against using at(). While it throws an exception, this is not of much help, since usually no tight exception checks are implemented around vector code. Further out_of_range errors are usally bugs, thus they should not be tracked using exceptions, but debug helpers and asserts.

Answer (score 4):

`libstdc++` has a mature [debug mode](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/debug_mode_using.html) using `-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG`.

`libc++` also has a [debug mode](http://libcxx.llvm.org/debug_mode.html) using `-D_LIBCPP_DEBUG` but as we can see this mailing list [discussion: Status of the libc++ debug mode](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.compilers.clang.devel/37051) it is incomplete:

> | My understanding is that this work was never completed and it's
>   probably broken/incomplete.
>
> That is correct.
>   It’s on my list of things to fix/implement, but it’s not something that I will get to anytime soon.

It does  seem to work for `std::vector` on `3.4` and up [see it live](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/or6XesH6RcjQRT1I), give the following program:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v = {0,1,2,3} ;

    std::cout << v[-1] << std::endl ;
}
```

it generates the following error:

> vector[] index out of bounds
>
> Aborted

Comment: See [updated libc++ debug mode documentation](https://libcxx.llvm.org/docs/DesignDocs/DebugMode.html)

Comment: See [mailing list thread here](http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/cfe-dev/2014-June/037298.html) I guess the archive moved :-p

Comment: The guidance is to not use LLVM's `libc++` *debug mode* (which been deprecated, and then removed), and instead use the various **sanitizers** to help detect code misbehavior.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Linux or OS X you should look into the address sanitizer:

http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AddressSanitizer.html

It introduces a 2x slowdown, but does a bunch of memory checking and may catch your bug.

Another amazing tool that has saved me countless times is valgrind. If you can run with valgrind it will catch a ton of memory bugs and leaks.

Comment: Note that AddressSanitizer will not catch all the logical bugs. For instance, if you have `std::vector<int> vec; vec.reserve(10); ` then accessing `vec[5]` is a bug but won't be detected by ASan since it is in allocated memory.

Answer (score 2):

```
#define _GLIBCXX_DEBUG
```

This enables all kinds of inline checking (see vector and debug/vector)

Comment: Does this work when used with libc++, or only with libstdc++? I'm currently using libc++ because <atomic> apparently isn't available when I'm compiling with libstdc++...

Comment: I'm not sure; I derived this by reading the headers in Cygwin; a.  Would be easy to check, though--write a simple program with a known length vector and see what happens when you read past it. <atomic> is available on gcc 4.5.3 but I'm not seeing it on 3.4.4

Comment: `_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` works in libstdc++, not libc++. On libc++, I believe that you can use `_LIBCPP_DEBUG2`. Store either a 0 or 1 to that value for various levels of debugging.