# Incorrect behavior of std::vector operator[]

Tags: c++, vector, clang, std, clang++

I have next code snippet. The idea is that vector has 5 items and I access 100's via operator[] which is supposed to lead to crash. But as you can see in output it works.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> vec(5, 1);
    vec[100] = 25;
    std::cout << "vec[100] = " << vec[100] << ", vec[99] = " << vec[99] <<
        ", vector size = " << vec.size() << 
        ", vector capacity = " << vec.capacity() << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
vec[100] = 25, vec[99] = 0, vector size = 5, vector capacity = 5
```

Compilation flags:

```
clang++ -W -Wall -std=c++14 -stdlib=libc++ vector_over_flow_test.cpp -o vector_overflow_test.bin
```

Clang version:

```
$clang++ --version
Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.3.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

According to [cpp reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at)

> Returns a reference to the element at specified location pos. No bounds checking is performed.

Is it a bug in implementation?

Comment: You even quote the documentation "no bounds checking is performed" but  you seem to expect that the compiler would actually check bounds and then crash if it was out of bounds

Comment: *Is it a bug in implementation?* -- Be serious now.  Did you really think that a compiler used by thousands of people around the world would get this simple thing wrong?  Of course it isn't an implementation issue -- if it was, `clang` would be laughed out of the business.

Comment: If you want bounds checking for `std::vector`, then you can turn it on with special compiler flags. Because it is undefined behaviour, a compiler is free to offer this option to you. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16467380/bounds-checking-of-stdvector-and-other-containers-in-clang as a starting point.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> which is supposed to lead to crash

No. This is just [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). The implementations are not required to crash; anything is possible, including seem working well. Note that you should never rely on it.

On the other hand, [std::vector::at](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at) do perform a bounds checking, and `std::out_of_range` will be thrown when getting out of the bound.

Answer (score 3):

It is not a bug according to your cited docs:

> Returns a reference to the element at specified location pos. No bounds checking is performed.

It is just fortune that it is not crash and worked properly.